# new line in javascript passed to get argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im using .net multiline control. The I use jQuery to get data from that control:

```
$('.detailsCommentContent').val()
```

in this moment when I alert that value new lines are visible.

Then I make request `www.example.com?commentContent= + "$('.detailsCommentContent').val()"`

And in the http request there are no newLines signs at this moment.

What should I do to keep this new Lines symbols ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to URL-encode the value:

```
var url = "http://www.yourpage.com?commentContent=" + 
  encodeURIComponent($('.detailsCommentContent').val());
```

Comment: It's `encodeURIComponent`, not `escapeURIComponent`. Fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I know - I swear it's a coin flip every single time I type that in. :-)  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it dangerous to send user comment to server using GET argument ?

Comment: Well that depends on what the comments might contain. If they're something like YouTube comments, then I think the only danger is to public mental health but there's no security issue. If the comments might include personal medical information, then that would be different.

Comment: It's quite easy. It violates the HTTP standards: RFC 2616: 13.9 Side Effects of GET and HEAD: "Unless the origin server explicitly prohibits the caching of their responses, the application of GET and HEAD methods to any resources SHOULD NOT have side effects that would lead to erroneous behavior if these responses are taken from a cache."

Comment: Oh well yes, that's definitely true - I had simply assumed that the OP had already accepted that the GET was improper but had moved on due to some other necessity.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `POST` request for data that changes something, not a `GET`. That way you can POST whatever data you like without encoding it, and best of all: bots that are just spidering your page can't do any damage to your site. See also http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I cant use webMethods and the only one way I figured out how to get asynchronously  data from server and send without using updatePanel is clean apsx site which renders what I want and receive it as json

Comment: If you have a page, then you can use POST. POST is not limited to WebMethods or something. Just change your `$.get` to `$.post`, and instead of `$.get('url?data', function (){})`, do `$.post('url', data, function () {})`.

Comment: I use something like this: var resultString = encodeURIComponent($('.detailsCommentContent').val());
                        $.getJSON('/api/rate-page.aspx?mcId=' + $('.activeDetails').val() + "&incomm=" + resultString, function (data) {

Answer (score 1):

`<Textarea>` elements store "new lines" based on the host operating system, and sometimes even just the browser.

Between windows, mac, and linux, this could be `\r\n`, `\n`, or `\r`.

`\r` is a "carriage return", and `\n` is a "line feed". (C++ people will be familiar with `crlf`)

These characters make up a new line.

**Here's the problem:**

When you get the value of a textarea, it doesn't *always* preserve the line marker when going to store to a variable. You can try and replace the line-break, or encode it as per @Pointy's answer.

This question's existed in a few forms, but they're all hard to find because we have a lot of differnt names for the line-break.

Basically, the browser hates you for some reason, you need to hide what you're doing because it's trying to be really really smart.

Answer (score 0):

use the escape() function on the value, or use a POST instead of a GET.